# Input value not rendered in popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Why the text binding work and the value doesn't work, if I select the element with ID with jquery and print her value in console, the value's the right but it's not showing.

```
<center>
  <h2>Popover Demo</h2>
  <div data-bind="template: {name: 'popoverTemplate', foreach: commands}"></div>
</center>

<script type="text/html" id="popoverTemplate">
    <div style="display:none;" data-bind="attr: {'id': $data.command + 'Content'}, template: {name: 'popoverContent', data: $data.content}"></div>    
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-bind='text: $data.command, popover: $data'></a>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="popoverContent">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" data-bind='value: $data.name'></p>
    <p>Email: <b data-bind='text: $data.email'></b></p>
</script>
```

​

Here is the complete example in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mounir/V3nVd/15/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete working example, I changed the `ko.applyBindings()` to `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` to include the binding context $root and $parent when we would like to associate a button for example to a function in a root viewModel.

```
$(element).click(function() {
            $(this).popover('toggle');
            var thePopover = document.getElementById(attribute.id+"-popover");
            childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(viewModel);
            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, thePopover);
        });
```

Take a look @ http://jsfiddle.net/mounir/Mv3nP/4/

Answer (score 2):

Your `.popover` copies the html of the rendered templates into a `data-` attribute.

It looks like the bindings do not apply on dynamically inserted html. And the `value:` binding (ko default) sets the input via the javascript `.value('sample text')` method. So in essence, the copied HTML:

```
<p>Name: <input type="text" data-bind='value: $data.name'></p>
<p>Email: <b data-bind='text: $data.email'>ben@msn.com</b></p>
```

is just:

```
<p>Name: <input type="text"></p>
<p>Email: <b>ben@msn.com</b></p>
```

Hence the empty `<input>` but populated `<b>` tag.

To get around this, you can have knockout set the `value` attribute of the `<input>` to the value required:

```
<p>Name: <input type="text" data-bind="attr: { value: $data.name }"></p>
<p>Email: <b data-bind="text: $data.email"></b></p>
```

This populates the `<input>`. But please remember, the values are no longer observable.

The values are updated every time `.popover` is called, but not if the observables are updated while the popover is showing. Neither are you able to update the observable by editing the `<input>`.

You should consider expanding your custom-binding to account for all of this, such as get the value from the `<input>` when the popover closes and put it back in the observable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Sethi.
Yeah, but if I wan't to still have my input observable, I should pass the viewModel in the init function, and apply the binding in the popover div. For each popover when the click event is hired I set the `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, thePopover);`

```
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var attribute = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var cssSelectorForPopoverTemplate = attribute.content;
        var popOverTemplate = "<div id='"+attribute.id+"-popver'>" + $(cssSelectorForPopoverTemplate).html() + "</div>";
        $(element).popover({
            content: popOverTemplate,
            html: true,
            trigger: 'manual'
        });

        $(element).click(function() {
            $(this).popover('toggle');
            var thePopover = document.getElementById(attribute.id+"-popver");
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, thePopover);
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: a working fiddle might be helpful for others. marking my answer as correct will be too.

Comment: Yeah of course, but your answer is not the one that solved my problem.

Comment: I understand that I didn't provide you with the custom-binding code, but I set you off in the right direction. And, after all, your question was "Why [does] the text binding work and the value doesn't work..." - which I answered ;)